# Как сделать постраничный вывод?

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите что надо сделать для постраничного вывода?

Имею пока что простой вывод всего из таблицы:

```
function sql($sql,$array)
{
    global $db;
    try
    {
        $start =  $db->prepare($sql);
        if ($array) $start -> execute($array);
        else $start -> execute();
        return $start;
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        exit("Не удалось выполнить запрос!");
    }
}

if ($_GET['m'] == 'news' OR !$_GET)
{
    $title = 'Новости';
    $news = sql("SELECT * FROM `News` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 100",false);
    foreach($news as $new)
    {
        $content.= '<div class="block" id="'.$new['id'].'">
        <div class="title"><a href="?n='.$new['id'].'" id="ajax" class="link">'.htmlspecialchars_decode($new['title']).'</a></div>
        <div class="new">'.htmlspecialchars_decode($new['content']).'</div>
        </div>';
    }
    if (!$content)
    {
        $content = Alert("Новостей нет.",false);
    }
}
```

Демо: https://w-0rld.ru/

Вывод кнопок планирую на такой верстке:

```
<div class="pages">
<!-- Текущая страница -->
<a class="disabled">1</a>
<!-- Другие страницы -->
<a href="?m=news&page=2">2</a>
<a href="?m=news&page=3">3</a>
<a href="?m=news&page=4">4</a>
<a href="?m=news&page=5">5</a>
<a href="?m=news&page=6">6</a>
<a href="?m=news&page=7">7</a>
<a href="?m=news&page=8">8</a>
<a href="?m=news&page=9">9</a>
<a href="?m=news&page=10">10</a>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Погуглил, везде старые примеры, не вызывающие доверия.

Answer (score 1):

```
function sql($sql, $page = 1, $array) {
    global $db;
    $limit = 20; // 20 записей на страницу
    $from = ($page == 2) ? $limit : 0; // Начиная от 0 записи
    $to = ($page == 2) ? ($from + $limit) : $limit; // Заканчивая 20-ой
    if($page > 2) {
        $from = ($limit * $page) - $limit;
        $to = $from + $limit;
    }
    try {
        $start =  $db->prepare($sql . " LIMIT ".$from.", ".$to);
        if ($array) $start -> execute($array);
        else $start -> execute();
        return $start;
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {exit("Не удалось выполнить запрос!");}
}
```

`LIMIT` в функцию передавать не нужно, в функции он сам подставится.

Вызов функции будет в таком виде:

```
$news = sql("SELECT * FROM `News` ORDER BY `id` DESC", 2, false); // в данном случае выбрана страница 2
```

***Сам код не тестировал, но суть должна быть понятна.***

Comment: Показали бы пример в отдельной функции, ибо моя функция была для простого получения результатов запроса (для сокращения кода), плюс не понятно каким образом можно выводить кнопки переключения для страниц. Я пока ещё новичок.

Comment: @W_0rld поставьте тогда правильный вопрос. Вы показываете то, что у вас есть и то, что хотите получить.

Comment: Тогда не буду пользоваться своим примером, скажем мне просто надо вывести все данные из таблицы "Table" выводя на каждую страницу по 10 записей из колонки "Row". Снизу должны быть кнопки переключения между страницами, страниц может быть сколько угодно (зависит от общего количества колонок). Текущая ссылка на страницу должна быть отмечена любым css-способом.

Comment: Я посмотрю как это делается исходя из вашего примера, и потом сам уже накручу функцию, судя по своему API.